# DropDownList won't trigger in an asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, postback

I have a asp:DropDownList in an asp:UpdatePanel and for some reason, the method on the server side is never called or triggered from the OnSelectedIndexChange method. I even tried adding an explicit asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger on the UpdatePanel to try to force it to happen but nothing. When I take the control out of the UpdatePanel, it will trigger OnSelectedIndexChange as intended but of course it now refreshes the whole page. What's the issue here? Here's my markup:

**MARKUP**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SurveyScriptManager" runat="server" />
<div id="container">

    <div class="divSurveyParametersHeaderRow">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udpSurveyParameters">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="divFilter">
                    <span><b>Title:</b></span>

                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        ToolTip="Select to add items" DataTextField="LookupItemName" DataValueField="LookupItemId">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Add..." Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkFilters" CssClass="chkFilters" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"></asp:CheckBoxList>

                </div>                        
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlItems" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlItems.DataSource = Logic.GetLookupItems();
            ddlItems.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chkFilters.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text + "<img src='Resources/delete.png'/>", Value = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value });
    }
```

Comment: The problem is probably not in the aspx but in code behind.

Comment: @VDWWD I've added the relevant code behind. The selected index change method is never being triggered, I have a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and it's never hit.